# How to protect www folder on windows

Tags: php, windows, security

I made an intranet for a shop and i am going to give the computer with intranet on it. I want to make sure he can not copy my files and install on another computer.

I want to protect the "www" folder in my Apache server. I am using AppServ. on local computer.

Checked some tools on the net like TrueCrypt, FolderEncrypt etc. All these encrypt the folder contents. If the www folder is encrypted, then my php won't work. Is there a way to lock the folder in windows without encrypting its contents.[ A little harder to crack then no lock at all]

I am using zend guard to protect the php file and it checks the hard disk name and model and computer model but this does not give %100 protection. I heard zend encode gets decoded online.

I need some suggestions.

```
$output = shell_exec('wmic diskdrive get model');
echo $output;
echo "<br>";
$output1 = shell_exec('wmic csproduct get name,vendor,identifyingNumber');
echo $output1;
```

Comment: The main question is: Is your product *that* valuable? If someone wants to crack it, he can do so anyway. So I'd not waste the same but rather spend it in making your product better so people are more likely to buy it.

Comment: You could create a new WindowsAccount, have him be the owner of the files, have him run all processes for the intranet (webserver, php, database, ...) and only give him the permissions to the files. Don't give the user the password, and don't give him the adminpassword either...

Comment: @Konerak: And then he magically boots a system called Linux and laughs at you..

Comment: @halfdan: there are always ways around, but linux can't decrypt NTFS-protected storage?

Answer (score 0):

You could obfuscate your php code or even compile it using for example http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/358/
It will produce a binary, which will be very difficult to look into and modify (although of course possible). 
Just obfuscating is also good, but not nearly as good as compiling.

As for actually make him not be able to copy files, you could 
1) run a truectrypt volume and log into it manually every time, and when he uses the computer, just restart it so the files will be encrypted. (Your shop will not work during that time of course)
2) do not give him administrator access, just make a limited account for him. (Which does not have access to protected files). This method will still make your files available if he takes out the harddrive to another computer, or boots from a livecd and copies them, or similair. 
3) just move the damn project from the computer that you want to give to another person... Dont make it more complicated than it is...

PS: Another great idea!
You could install a virtualbox or similair virtualisation software on your computer, and install your server in there, configuring all the network so that it would be accessible from the outside. That Vbox will be protected by the password and possibly even with truecrypt, inside the guest machine of course. And then you tell that person that if he wants to restart your computer he must first take Pause on the guest machine, and after the restart, Resume the virtual machine. That way the host can be restarted without you having to enter the truecrypt password again.

(truecrypt in this setup is needed so that that person will not be able to just take the harddrive files of the virtual machine and copy them).

That's the way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem that cryptography can solve.  If the server is compromised then any key on the machine to decrypt the www folder is also compromised.

What you **should do**  is make your www folder and all of its contents **read only**.  There are exploits where they are trying to drop a .php file into your web root and execute them.  This also prevents malware from defacing your website.  There are hackers that break into websites only to add an `<iframe>` to hack browsers that visits the website.